# Create NFA where |w|_a is divisible by 2 or |w|_b is divisible by 3

Tags: automata, finite-automata

I have to create an NFA $\mathcal{A}$ that accepts the language $L = \{w \in \Sigma^* \ |  \ |w|_a \ \text{is divisible by 2 or} \ |w|_b \ \text{is divisible by 3} \}$

So the NFA only accepts words with $|w|_a \ mod \ 2 = 0$ or $|w|_b \ mod \ 3 = 0$.

[This is the NFA that I constructed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTsTi.png) but it is not enough. What is the full correct NFA?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

1- The language $L$ can be written as the union of two simple regular languages.

2- $\epsilon$ is in the language.

3- When you design an automaton for all words $w$ with $\#_a(w) \mod 2 \equiv 0$, then you should allow for an arbitrary number of $b$'s to appear anywhere in the input $w$.